# Is it possible to generate an XFDF file from a Word document?

Tags: pdf, ms-word, xfdf

I have tried finding a way to generate an XFDF file from a Word document, because I have some important information in my Word document which I need to use in my PDF.
So I wanna get the XFDF and merge it with my PDF.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to opening your PDF in Adobe Acrobat and exporting as XFDF format instead of using Word?

***Main Menu -> Forms -> Manage form data -> Export data (Select XFDF Format)***

Hope I'm of assistance, free for any questions.

Good luck -Stuart

Comment: I need to get the information from a Word document, that why I can't open it with Adobe Acrobat

Comment: Export the word document as a pdf then open the pdf in Acrobat, from here follow the steps I mentioned previously. Should work fine for what you're doing.